# Time Difference by Row

Tags: mysql

I want to get the time difference between multiple rows

```
  Sl_id   ID     ShortLeave               createddate

    15    8     2015-10-02 13:10:07   2015-02-11 16:08:01
    16    8     2015-10-02 14:05:07   2015-02-11 16:08:01
```

I need to get the Short Leave Difference filter by `where Id=1`. I tried

```
SELECT  timediff(A.shortleave,B.shortleave) AS timedifference
FROM shortL A  JOIN shortL B ON B.id = A.id 
where A.Id=1
group by A.ID,A.ShortLeave ;
```

but i got two rows

```
'00:00:00'
'00:55:00'
```

It happens because of `Sl_id`. So please help me how i get only one row for multiple rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my query like

```
SELECT  timediff(A.shortleave,B.shortleave) AS timedifference
FROM shortL A  JOIN shortL B ON B.id = A.id 
where A.Id=1
group by A.ID,A.ShortLeave order by timedifference desc limit 1;
```

By doing this i always got the latest column. In this i got only `'00:55:00'` as a result and that's ok.